# OpenCV: Drawing on an image

Tags: image, drawing, opencv, vision

I am working on a program using the OpenCV library (though I am quite a noob on it). One of the things I need to do is to draw on the image. I looked at the OpenCV drawing functions and they all seem pretty simple (Circle, Line, etc), however the program won't compile! It says this to be exact: error C3861: 'Line': identifier not found.
Is there something I haven't installed? I used the tutorial on http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B_VS2008 to install OpenCV  on Visual Studio 2008 and so far this is the only real problem I have.
Please help me! I need this program working as soon as possible!

Answer (score 4):

The function to draw a line in the OpenCV C API is named [`cvLine`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/drawing_functions.html#cvLine), not `Line`.

Comment: Ok... That was easy. Nothing was said in the site -_- http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/drawing_functions.html
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Juls The link you posted is for the Python documentation, which is why the function names are different.

Comment: +1 Accurate. Juls, don't forget to vote up on his answer or accept it as the official solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have fallen victim of the following common mistake:
C includes are in `#include <opencv/core.h>` etc, whereas
C++ includes are:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <oppencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Include these for drawing and showing the image. Use `using namespace cv;` then 
you don't have to write `cv::line` just `line` and everything will be working fine.
I had to battle with the very same problem when I began. ;)

(And btw use `cv::Mat` for c++.)

Answer (score 0):

You can now easily paint on OpenCV images. For this you need to call the `setMouseCallback(‘window_name’,image_name)` function on opencv. After that you can easily handle the Mouse Callback Function upon your images. Then you need to detect the `cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN, cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP` events. By checking the proper boolean condition you need to decide how you like to interact with the OpenCV images.

```
def paint_draw(event,former_x,former_y,flags,param):
    global current_former_x,current_former_y,drawing, mode

    if event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing=True
        current_former_x,current_former_y=former_x,former_y

    elif event==cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing==True:
            if mode==True:
                cv2.line(image,(current_former_x,current_former_y),(former_x,former_y),(0,0,255),5)
                current_former_x = former_x
                current_former_y = former_y
    elif event==cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing=False
        if mode==True:
            cv2.line(image,(current_former_x,current_former_y),(former_x,former_y),(0,0,255),5)
            current_former_x = former_x
            current_former_y = former_y
    return former_x,former_y
```

For details you can see link: [How to Paint on OpenCV Images and Save the Image](http://www.life2coding.com/paint-opencv-images-save-image/)

Output:

[image]